# Jump to console screen position defined by entering coordinate

Tags: c++, codeblocks

I have simple console application created with Codeblocks c++ IDE. I would like to jump my cursor to any screen position by entering coordinate. How to achieve that?

Comment: I'd suggest using a library like [ncurses](https://www.gnu.org/software/ncurses/ncurses.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use functions from [Windows Console API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/console-reference).
For that, you just need to include [windows.h](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows.h) header.

> *SetConsoleCursorPosition( HANDLE,COORD )* should do the trick.

Take a look at the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/setconsolecursorposition?redirectedfrom=MSDN#parameters) from *Microsoft Docs.*

Here's a demo example:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<windows.h>
#include<cstdio>

using namespace std;

void changeCursor( int columnPos, int rowPos )
{
   HANDLE handle;      /// A HANDLE TO CONSOLE SCREEN BUFFER

   /// COORD STRUCTURE CONTAINS THE COLUMN AND ROW
   /// OF SCREEN BUFFER CHARACTER CELL
   COORD coord;

   coord.X = columnPos;
   coord.Y = rowPos;

   /// RETURNS A HANDLE TO THE SPECIFIED DEVICE.

   handle = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);   /// STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE MEANS STANDARD
                                            /// OUTPUT DEVICE(console screen buffer)

   SetConsoleCursorPosition( handle,coord );   /// SETS CURSOR POSITION IN SPECIFIED
                                            /// CONSOLE SCREEN BUFFER
}

int main()
{
   int xCoord,yCoord;
   cout<<"Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of \nthe printing and typesetting industry.\nLorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard \ndummy text ever since the 1500.";

   cout<<endl<<endl<<"Coordinates of Column and Row(zero indexed): ";

   cin>>xCoord>>yCoord;

   getchar();
   changeCursor(xCoord,yCoord);        /// YOUR FUNCTION TO SET NEW CURSOR

   getchar();          /// KEEP THE CONSOLE FROM TERMINATING

   return 0;
}
```

**Output:**

```
Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of
the printing and typesetting industry.
Lor*e*m Ipsum has been the industry's standard
dummy text ever since the 1500.

Coordinates of Column and Row(zero indexed): 3 2
```

Notice here the coordinates need to be measured from **TOP LEFT position** i.e. (0,0) position of console screen.

The X ,Y values are **Character Positions** as they are pointing to **SCREEN BUFFER CHARACTER CELL.**

See a [Sample Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MhxSM.png) here with specified cursor position.